# Can we combine two html selector with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two html button element like this.

```
<input type="button" class="button-a" value="Button a"/>  
<input type="button" class="button-b" value="Button b"/>
```

So on clicking any of the button I want to trigger the same event. So I can do that by writing  some jquery code like.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //button-a click event
    $('.button-a').click(function(){
      alert("The event triggered");
    });

    //button-b click event
    $('.button-b').click(function(){
      alert("The event triggered");
    });
 });
</script>
```

So can we combine both the `event()` together like OR condition with jQuery?

Comment: comma separated, $('.button-a,.button-b')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.button-a, .button-b').click(function(){
          alert("The event triggered");
    });
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gNths/

Comment: Hi Alessandro Minoccheri, Thanks for your answer. I tried comma separated class like you mentioned earlier it didn't work for me.

Comment: You are welcome, I hope that you have solved your problem with this code :)

Comment: I have added an example into jsfiddle see this and see that works! http://jsfiddle.net/gNths/

Answer (score 1):

They are selectors, so same applies as css you just need to comma separate like you do in css, `$('.button-a,.button-b')`

Answer (score 0):

Try `$('[class^="button-"]').click( function() {...} );`

Answer (score 0):

Yup. This should do it:

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.button-a, .button-b').click(function() { 
        alert("The event triggered");    
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Formatting off as i posting from my phone.;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //button-a click event
    $('.button-a').click(function(){
      ButtonClick("#button_a");
    });

    //button-b click event
    $('.button-b').click(function(){
      ButtonClick("#button_b");
    });
 });

function ButtonClick(id){
 //do something
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>  
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.button-a, .button-b').click(function(){
              alert("The event triggered");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This script worked for me. Thanks everyone for your time.